# how to distinguish 2 submits from each other in php with $_POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am having a form in which 2 inputs like below:

```
<input class="view" type="submit" name="viewonly" value="View">
<input class="submit" type="submit" name="vote" value="Vote">
```

I want to achieve this:

```
if(hit on input with name 'viewonly') {
echo 'you choose viewonly';
}
elseif(hit on input with name 'vote') {
echo 'you choose vote';
}
```

How can i do that?

**Update:** 
My form:

```
<form method="post" id="quickpoll">
.........
<input class="view" type="submit" name="quickpollsubmit" value="View">
<input class="quickpollsubmit" type="submit" name="quickpollsubmit" value="Vote">
   </form>
```

The ajax call:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#quickpoll', function()
{
var data = $(this).serialize();
$.ajax({

    type : 'POST',
    url  : 'quickpoll_vote.php',
    data : data,
    success :  function(data)
               {                        
                    $("#quickpoll").fadeOut(500).hide(function()
                    {
                        $(".quickpollwrapper").fadeIn(500).show(function()
                        {
                            $(".quickpollwrapper").html(data);

                        });


                    });

               }
    });
    return false;
});
```

**quickpoll_vote.php**

```
if($_POST)
{

    if($_POST['quickpollsubmit'] == 'Vote') {
    echo 'you did vote and not view only';
    }
```

The echo does not appear, so the problem is i think in the AJAX call?

Comment: if both buttons have the same name, then `$_POST['btnName']` will have the value of whichever one was clicked. I also believe that only whichever button was clicked would be in the `$_POST` data if they have different names. Been a while since I've dealt with this.

Comment: use `isset()` on a conditional

Comment: Kuhn is right. Give them the same name and check for different value.

Comment: I tried it with the same name and different values but without result; problem is in the AJAX call? Post above updated

Comment: @JackMaessen I posted something below before you posted your full/real code. If this is a jquery issue, I am so not the guy for this. I work serverside mostly. If what I posted below isn't what you were looking for, please tell me so I can delete it and avoiding possible downvotes.

Comment: @Fred unfortunately, i tried your option as well but also without result

Comment: @JackMaessen No worries. I deleted it. Good luck ;-) wish I could have been of more help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can little change you code like this:

```
<input class="view myclass" type="button" name="viewonly" value="View">
<input class="submit myclass" type="button" name="vote" value="Vote">
<script language="javascript">
     $('.myclass').click(function() {
         clickbuttonname = $(this).attr('name');
         var data = $(this).serialize()+'&clickbuttonname='+clickbuttonname;
         .....
     })
</script>
```